# Generify boolean check for Number subclasses

Tags: java

I want to create a method that, with an object called value as the input, is able to do both:

```
value instanceof Double && (Double.isInfinite((Double) value) || Double.isNaN((Double) value))
value instanceof Float && (Float.isInfinite((Float) value) || Float.isNaN((Float) value))
```

So my idea is to pass in the parameters, in addition to value, the class to be used in each case. The signature of the method could be something like:

```
isInfiniteOrNaN(Object value, ??? type)
```

So I can call it to get the desired behavior as:

```
isInfiniteOrNaN(value, Double)
isInfiniteOrNaN(value, Float)
```

Both `Float` and `Double` extends from `Number`, but `Number` has not the methods `isInfinite` or `isNan` so I cannot use the super class.

Is any way to do it in Java? (I use java 10 at the moment)

I would rather prefer easy to read and understand code than the most efficient or fast, but if it can be both easy & fast, will be top!

Comment: How about using just the primitive `double`? Is `value` nullable?

Comment: good question. in this situation, yes, it is nullable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the primitive `double` as the type of `value` solves it:

```
static boolean isInfiniteOrNaN(double value) {
    return Double.isInfinite(value) || Double.isNaN(value);
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    System.out.println(isInfiniteOrNaN(Double.NaN)); //true
    System.out.println(isInfiniteOrNaN(Float.NaN)); //true
}
```

For nullable doubles and floats, it can be wrapped in a null-safe version taking `Number`, but calling `doubleValue()` to get the primitive:

```
static boolean isInfiniteOrNaN(Number value) {
    return value == null || Double.isInfinite(value.doubleValue());
}
```

This last version works when tested with both `Double.valueOf(Double.NaN)` and `Float.valueOf(Float.NaN)`

Comment: amazing @ernest_k, only one thing left, even when Double is bigger than Float, the infinity is the same for them both?

Comment: @Arcones Yeah, the infinity values don't represent their respective max_value

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use reflection (sort of):

```
private static boolean isInfiniteOrNaN(Object x) {
    MethodType methodType = MethodType.methodType(boolean.class);
    Lookup l = MethodHandles.lookup();
    try {
        MethodHandle isInfinite = l.findVirtual(x.getClass(), "isInfinite", methodType);
        MethodHandle isNaN = l.findVirtual(x.getClass(), "isNaN", methodType);
        return (boolean) isInfinite.invoke(x) || (boolean) isNaN.invoke(x);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the support, but I feel this a little overwhelming for the task